# PHP Generate CSV from 500k+ SQL rows

Tags: php, oracle

I'm facing a problem since ages. I've got a large data set of 500 000 rows and I want to print them to a CSV.

On a first case, I need to do calculations from the columns on a row to determine a "result" column. I've found a solution to that. I'm using "fetch" and doing calculation row by row and printing gradually to my csv

Simplified example :

```
|---------------------------------------|
| ID | type | var1 | var2 | var1 * var2 |
|---------------------------------------|
| 0  |  car |    2 |    5 |          10 |
| 1  | moto |    4 |    8 |          32 |
| 2  |  car |    0 |    2 |           2 |
|---------------------------------------|
```

On a second case, I need, from 500k rows, to print calculation involving large amount of rows from these 500k (It can be up to group of 10k+ rows).

Simplified example :

```
|-----------------------------|
| type |      sum var1 * var2 |
|-----------------------------|
|  car |             87677670 |
| moto |              3232435 |
|-----------------------------|
```

BUT, calculations are far more complicated that just a sum of a multiplication. Traduction : they can't be done directly in SQL.

My problem is that if I get all my cars from my database to my php app to loop over, my php memory_limit would be reach. How can I do this gradually like the first example ?

Not : I'm using Oracle 12c and PHP 5.3.5

Comment: I'm not sure this is answerable without focussing more on the details of the operation you're trying to do with the data. The basic answer is "fetch some rows, process them, and fetch some more", but what that looks like depends what "process them" needs to look like.

Comment: @BadHorsie - *I'm using Oracle 12c*

Comment: Just increase the memory limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the memory used by making your calculations by blocks. With SQL you can loop multiple request with only a specific amount of rows on each requests.

With Oracle this can be done with `FETCH` and `OFFSET`. Here is a piece of [documentation](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-fetch/) where you will find everything you need.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that will help me a lot. I've just a question, the documentation say that it can retrieve the 5 first rows for example. How do i get the 5 next and so on ?

Comment: With `OFFSET`, for example, `OFFSET 5 ROWS` with `FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY` will get the rows 6 to 10, `OFFSET 10 ROWS` the rows 11 to 15. See the last example.

Comment: Ok so i need to modify my request gradually. I'll try that